# Find MailType in Outlook Addin

Tags: outlook, add-in

Am creating an outlook add in with c#.net . When i try to forward a mail thread , is it possible to get all mail thread as mailItem array object . I wanted to check a value in the mail body which created newly and not in the mail thread. If i could fetch the mail thread , i can write a condition for the first item which is my new mail .

Is there an option to check the newly created mail is forward , Reply or ReplyToall

Please help me .

Answer (score 0):

Call MailItem.GetConversation (Outlook 2010 and up) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862527.aspx